# Flutter. ShaderMask cannot take alignment from the local Container

Tags: flutter, shader

I have very wired behavior using `ShaderMask` for some reason. I have bunch of different `Widgets` inside `SingleScrollView`. And one of them it's `Text` with `ShaderMask`. During launch the the screen, I don't have any mask, **until I make some scroll**.

```
            ShaderMask(
                shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                  return  LinearGradient(
                    tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                    colors: <Color>[Colors.transparent, Colors.white],
                  ).createShader(bounds);
                },
                child: Text(
                  sampleDetails,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: AppDimens.textSizeSmall),
                ),
              ),
```

From the debugging I have found, it's tight to the `Alignment` over screen. For ex. changing the `Alignment` to the horizontal will make effect on this page without scrolling (because scroll on the page is vertical!).

```
                LinearGradient(
                    tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                    colors: <Color>[Colors.transparent, Colors.white],
                  ).createShader(bounds);
```

I don't see any documentation details about pivot for starting `Shaders` so this it's very annoying.  Any idea how change it to work only based on specific box?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for troubling, there is a way to do it. It's to take correct rect for shaders, based on size of widget. Main line would be next `createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height))`.

```
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (rect) {
    return LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
    ).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
  },
  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/chrome.png',
    height: 400,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
),
```